# Using a Like statement to find a JSON value in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to find a website page path with a metadata column in big query. So for example, the metadata field might look like:

```json
[
  "{\"Name\":\"PageVisit\",\"Value\":\"/abc/hello-world-123/\",\"IgnoreForCache\":false}",
  "{\"Name\":\"pageTitle\",\"Value\":\"Hello World\",\"IgnoreForCache\":false}",
  "{\"Name\":\"dateTime\",\"Value\":\"2023-08-16T12:00:00\",\"IgnoreForCache\":false}",
  "{\"Name\":\"PageHostName\",\"Value\":\"thisismywebsite.com\",\"IgnoreForCache\":false}",
  "{\"Name\":\"PagePath\",\"Value\":\"/alpha/beta-delta-123/\",\"IgnoreForCache\":false}"
]
```

In this case what I am interested in finding is any row where the metadata column contains

```
PagePath\",\"Value\":\"/alpha/beta-delta-123
```

PagePath needs to be included so that I can differentiate between PageVisit and PagePath.

I know " and \ are escape characters, and next to each other also pose a problem. So I tried doing

```sql
SELECT metadata 
FROM table1
WHERE metadata LIKE '''%PagePath\",\"Value\":\"/alpha/beta-delta-123%'''
```

to cancel out the escape characters. I think a JSON_EXTRACT or related keyword might be what I need but unsure how to use that.

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just unnest the array as rows and then extract the JSON Value

```sql
SELECT
  JSON_VALUE(event, '$.Name') AS Name,
  JSON_VALUE(event, '$.Name') = 'PagePath' AS is_page_path
FROM UNNEST([
  "{\"Name\":\"PageVisit\",\"Value\":\"/abc/hello-world-123/\",\"IgnoreForCache\":false}",
  "{\"Name\":\"pageTitle\",\"Value\":\"Hello World\",\"IgnoreForCache\":false}",
  "{\"Name\":\"dateTime\",\"Value\":\"2023-08-16T12:00:00\",\"IgnoreForCache\":false}",
  "{\"Name\":\"PageHostName\",\"Value\":\"thisismywebsite.com\",\"IgnoreForCache\":false}",
  "{\"Name\":\"PagePath\",\"Value\":\"/alpha/beta-delta-123/\",\"IgnoreForCache\":false}"
]) AS event
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response! One question though, the data I would be unnesting is in a column "metadata" within table1. So, each row in the metadata column contains an array like you showed in your unnested statement. How would I go about that unnested statement for an entire column to then be able to filter what I'm looking for, rather than just a one specific array in a row within the metadata column?